# Итерация списка словарей, удаление одинаковых значений

Tags: python, словари

Добрый день, имеется следующий список словарей:

```
example = [    
    { 'name' : 'John', 'name2' : 'Mike'  },
    { 'name' : 'Smith', 'name2' : 'John' },
    { 'name' : 'Bob', 'name2' : 'Bob' },
    { 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Smith' },
    { 'name' : 'Mike', 'name2' : 'Maria' }
    ]
```

Посоветуйте прием (как итерировать и преобразовывать), чтобы получишь на выходе список данного вида:

```
output = [
{ 'name' : 'John' },
{ 'name' : 'Mike' },
{ 'name' : 'Smith' },
{ 'name' : 'Bob' },
{ 'name' : 'Maria' }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
output = [{'name': x} for x in set(reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [x.values() for x in example]))]
```

тот же код в подробностях:

```
>>> names = [x.values() for x in example]
>>> names
[['Mike', 'John'], ['John', 'Smith'], ['Bob', 'Bob'], ['Smith', 'Mike'], ['Maria', 'Mike']]
>>> names = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, names)
>>> names
['Mike', 'John', 'John', 'Smith', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Smith', 'Mike', 'Maria', 'Mike']
>>> names = set(names)
>>> names
set(['Mike', 'John', 'Smith', 'Bob', 'Maria'])
>>> output = [{'name': x} for x in names]
>>> output
[{'name': 'Mike'}, {'name': 'John'}, {'name': 'Smith'}, {'name': 'Bob'}, {'name': 'Maria'}]
```

Comment: Возможно, так было бы проще, без сплющивания списка =)

    output = [{'name': x['name']} for x in example]

Comment: Так в результат не попадают имена из второго столбца и вывод не уникален

    [{'name': 'John'},
     {'name': 'Smith'},
     {'name': 'Bob'},
     {'name': 'Mike'},
     {'name': 'Mike'}]

Comment: Точно, я не сразу понял задачу)

Answer (score 0):

```
uniq_names = set(name for d in example for name in d.values())
output = [{'name': name} for name in uniq_names]
```

- чтобы все имена из списка словарей извлечь, используется генератор с вложенным циклом
- чтобы удалить дубликаты, используется `set()`
- чтобы создать результирующий список словарей, используется простой генератор списков

#### Результат

```
[{'name': 'Mike'},
 {'name': 'Bob'},
 {'name': 'Smith'},
 {'name': 'John'},
 {'name': 'Maria'}]
```